Transferring custom stylesheet to Wolfram 14
I built my own stylesheet in Mathematica some versions ago. It's the only one I ever built, I can't remember how I did it, and it quietly lived in my Format/Stylesheet menu. I upgraded to Wolfram 14 and it's not in the menu anymore. I am on a Mac. Can anyone help me import the stylesheet into Wolfram 14?

Look into MigrateSettingsToWolframApp
